# I have an excel sheet of about 10,000 rows, how can I randomly select a text from another sheet which has only about 1000 rows which errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet1 of about 10,000 rows, how can I randomly select a text from another sheet which has only about 1000 rows which errors
I tried many formulas and all showing error

```
=INDEX(HEX!$I$2:$I$257;RANDBETWEEN(2;257))
=INDEX(Colors[@Color];RANDBETWEEN(1;ROWS(Colors[@Color])))
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  With the second you would remove both `@` and it will refer to the whole column.  With the first the randbetween range should be `1;256`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
=INDEX(HEX!$I$2:$I$257;RANDBETWEEN(1,256))
=INDEX(HEX!$I$2:$I$257;RANDBETWEEN(1;256))
```

(Second formula uses `;` instead of `,`)

I think the problem is your array isn't 2:257, it's viewed as 1 - 256 rows, so the index is reading your formula as misaligned arrays.